# C++ compiler flags for profiling in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

To accurately profile an application, under `linux`, it is recommended to have optimizations on and debug symbols on via compile options `-O2 -g` for `gcc` or `g++`. This enables profiling to include the user's C++ code and not point to assembly code instead as possible hotspots, for instance. See for instance, [here](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html).

In Visual Studio IDE, for usage of profilers, what are the equivalent compile/linking options?

In Release mode of Visual Studio, under "Whole Program Optimization" property sheet that comes loaded by default, the `Debug Information Format` gets set to `Program Database` with command line option `/Zi`. See image:

[image]

Is this the Visual Studio/Windows/MSVC (Cl.exe, MSBuild.exe) equivalent of `-O2 -g`? Or are there any other equivalent settings?

ETA: Under the default Visual Studio 2019 release mode settings, the following flags are set:

```
/permissive- /ifcOutput "x64\Release\" /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /I"E:\local\boost_1_72_0" /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /FC /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /FA /Fp"x64\Release\windows.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

Comment: @ChrisMM I think that's a configuration that CMake generates, not something that is part of visual studio

Comment: @ChrisMM Is this part of a preconfigured property sheet? I am unable to find this option in the solution configuration dialog box.

Comment: My mistake, @AlanBirtles is correct. Been a while since I used profiling without CMake.

Comment: `/Zi` is needed for the pdb files for debugging. Usually, `/O2` is also used (under optimization)

Comment: Yes, the command line flags that seem to come pre-loaded under Release Mode by default includes /O2. I have updated the OP with the complete list of default flags. I don't want to unnecessarily add "too much" debugging information so that the application profiling gets distorted due to this. Hence this query. Essentially, all I need is for the profiler to point to the C++ code and not the assembly code as hotspots with as little additional overhead as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the project properties, under C++ optimization. The IDE tells you everything.

[image]

Comment: Under Release mode, optimizations are anyway turned on and set to "maximum optimization favor speed/O2". The question in the OP is not about whether optimization should be turned on or off (they should be on), but how to set for debug symbols *as minimally as possible* in release mode so that hotspots can point to user's C++ code and not the assembly code.

Comment: @Tryer: this answer shows where options are set and how to know their meaning.